# PHP preg_match for getting a string out with variable length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following string example: `034a412f500535454e5`
Here I would get the 500 out.
The search-string has always 8 digits in front and 8 digits behind. The "500" can have a different lenght of digits (p.ex. 12345).

With a lot of trial end error I found that

```
preg_match('/(.{8})(.*)(.{13})/', $a, $matches);
```

It works. But I tink that not the way it is.

I do not understand why the left side has {8} and the right is {13}.

I get my String at following:

```
$lastInsertedId = 500;
$numArray = str_split(bin2hex(random_bytes(8)), 8);
$newArray = [$numArray[0],$lastInsertedId,$numArray[1]]; 
$a = vsprintf('%s%s%s',$newArray);
```

by using:

```
preg_match('/^.{8}\K.*(?=.{8}$)/', $a, $matches);
```

the result is 50053545. It will not gives the right value back.

by using:

```
preg_match('/^.{8}\K.*(?=.{8}$)/', '034a412f500535454e5', $matches);
```

it gives 500 back

Whats wrong?

gettype($a) gives string back.
I'am on php 8.1.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that with a regex, you can use

```
^.{8}\K.*(?=.{8}$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/InLtdL/2). Use the `s` flag if the string contains line breaks.

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `.{8}` - eight chars
- `\K` - omit what was matched so far
- `.*` - any zero or more chars
- `(?=.{8}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires any eight chars followed by the end of string location to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Also, consider using [`substr`](https://3v4l.org/vnd2q):

```php
$text = '034a412f500535454e5';
echo substr($text, 8, strlen($text)-16); // => 500
```

Comment: Thx Wiktor. I edited my question. Wit both of your proposals I have the same problem.

Comment: With preg_match('/^.{8}\K.*(?=.{13}$)/', $a, $matches);  this works, again with the 13

Comment: @hamburger That is not related to regex. Anyway, I get "*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "RT" in /tmp/preview:6*" error when trying your code.

Comment: RT is deleted, it is only a linefeed

Comment: @hamburger I get `500`, see [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/kheWg).

Answer (score 0):

vsprintf gives a wrong number of digits back.
strlen('034a412f500535454e5') gives 19
strlen($a) gives 25.
I'am using sprintf instead.